# MongoDB on Node.js doesn't work, it returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In the following code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name', function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('col_name');
    console.log(collection.find().toArray(function(err, items){}));

});
```

When I run the above, it doesn't return any results and instead returns `undefined`. What am I missing?

Also, in order to confirm there exist some collections on the db, which there are, I tried to add `console.log(db.getCollectionNames());`, but it looks like it has no such method in Node.js driver. So is it still possible to confirm the existence of collections? (Anyway I just want to use it as debug in these situations - usually I don't need the method though).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't log your entire `find()` function, do the checking in the callback:

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, items){
    console.log(items);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked as expected. Could you also answer the `getCollectionNames()` part? I'd like to know how to get collection names if it's also feasible on MongoDB driver.

Comment: Afraid that one is out of my reach, just recently started up with the Mongo, Node stack, so I'm still learning myself!

Answer (score 2):

For the getCollectionNames() part, the method is actually called collectionNames() in the mongodb native driver :

```
db.collectionNames(function (err, list) {console.log(list)});
```

Comment: db.collectionNames(function(err,collections){}); gives me TypeError: db.collectionNames is not a function as does db.getCollectionNames(function(err,collections){});